# Game restarts after lose focus Unity iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have such problem:
After lose focus, my application restarts, I'm trying to play with custom behaviours, but it isn't work.
Platform: iOS
Unity: 2020.3.26f1

Comment: That’s down to iOS. For the most part

Comment: Check your app's memory consumed. Sounds like it was killed by system in background.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem but in Android. I searched for hours and tried many different things.
The problem was that I had a piece of code well hidden invoking Unity method OnApplicationPause(). That method was the one responsible for closing the window. Double check if that's not ur case or something like it!